# How to differentiate Virtual user vs Real user?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, scalability, load-testing

What is the difference between virtual user vs real user in application point of view?

Comment: use captcha dude ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a real user is mostly (as the word implies) a real user sitting in front of an application is a virtual user (VU) "someone" who is able to use multiple connections at the same time. I used this mostly on load tests where an RU gives you the 1:1 speed and a VU a N:1 (if it is not a loadbalanced server). There is a good documentation about VUs here http://support.loadimpact.com/knowledgebase/articles/174260-what-are-virtual-users-vus.

To differentiate the two is hard but can be done by inspecting the header elements of the users. When you see the same header segmentation (lets say Webkit Browser) with the same access ip/mac/location at almost the same time you are most probably facing a VU. If the time differs greatly, it is rather a real user. If you like an example with Google Analytics, here is the source for you: http://blog.loadimpact.com/blog/monthly-visits-concurrent-users/